# Get only child terms of custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, wp-list-categories

I have category "trekking" with others chld categories. I need get only trekking child categories but i can't do it. This is my code (works fine, only I must exclude all the others categories but that is not a good/dynamic solution). Thanks!

```
<ul class="fordesktop">
<?php $customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('portfolio');
$category = get_category_by_slug( 'trekking' );
if(count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0)
{
     foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax)
     {
         $args = array(
              'orderby' => 'name',
              'show_count' => 0,
              'pad_counts' => 0,
              'hierarchical' => 0,
              'taxonomy' => $tax,
              'title_li' => '',
              'child_of' => $category,
             'exclude' => '10, 19, 20, 21, 22, 26, 29, 30, 31, 35, 36, 37, 41, 42, 43, 44',
             'hide_title_if_empty' => 0
            );

         wp_list_categories( $args );
     }
} ?></ul>
```

Another way is the next code, but I can't hide empty terms:

```
<?php
$term_id = 10;
$taxonomy_name = 'portfolio_category';
$termchildren = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
 
echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $termchildren as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $child, $taxonomy_name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `get_term_children()`:

```
// This will give you an array with the ID's of all child categories of 'trekking':
$cat = get_category_by_slug('trekking');
$cat_id = $cat->term_id;
$child_cat_ids = get_term_children($cat_id, 'category');
```

**An alternative approach, if you prefer a list of category objects, instead of IDs would be:**

```
$cat = get_category_by_slug('trekking');
$cat_id = $cat->term_id;
$child_cats = get_categories(['parent' => $cat_id]);
```

See more info here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_children/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/

EDIT:

if you want to use `wp_list_categories()` in your code, try this:

```
$cat = get_category_by_slug('trekking');
$cat_id = $cat->term_id;
$args = array(
        'child_of'   => $cat_id,
);
wp_list_categories($args);
```

EDIT 2:

Adjusted the solution for custom taxonomies:

```
$tax = get_term_by('slug', 'trekking', 'portfolio');
$tax_id = $tax->term_id;
$args = array(
'child_of'   => $tax_id,
'taxonomy' => 'portfolio',
'orderby' => 'name',
'show_count' => 0,
'pad_counts' => 0,
'hierarchical' => 0,     
'title_li' => '',
'hide_title_if_empty' => 0
);
wp_list_categories($args);
```

Comment: wow! i take a lot of time for this. How can implement that in my code? If you can help me of course. thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your use-case, I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks but that get post categories, not custom post (portfolio) or custom post categories  (portfolio_category). and i think don't hide empty terms like my code. Maybe i does something wrong?

Comment: Try Edit 2 - you may need to fiddle with it a bit because I'm writing this off the top of my head :)